# How to scale variables with wide ranges and display the same in a single plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have created the following dataframe

```
 # Create a dataframe

  Column1 <- c(1:30)
  Column1 <- paste0('Month_', as.character(Column1))
  paste0('Column', as.character(Column1))
  Variable <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", 'E')
  DF <- data.frame(Column1, Variable)
  DF$value <- 0
  DF$value[DF$Variable == "A"] <- runif(length(DF$value[DF$Variable == "A"]), 
      min = 10000, max = 50000)
  DF$value[DF$Variable == "B"] <- runif(length(DF$value[DF$Variable == "A"]), 
      min = 100, max = 500)
  DF$value[DF$Variable=="C"] <- runif(length(DF$value[DF$Variable=="A"]),
      min = 100, max = 500)
  DF$value[DF$Variabl e== "D"] <- runif(length(DF$value[DF$Variable == "A"]), 
      min = 100, max = 500)
  DF$value[DF$Variable == "E"] <- runif(length(DF$value[DF$Variable=="A"]),
      min = 100, max = 500)
```

Next I have imported the libraries to create the graph

```
  # We  now import the libraries

   library(readxl)
   require(plotly)
   require(reshape2)
   require(ggplot2)
   require(janitor)

   # We now create a chart

   p1 <- ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = Column1, y = value, colour = 
       Variable)) +
   geom_bar(data = DF[DF$Variable == "A",], aes(x = Column1, y = value,
       fill=Variable), stat = 'identity') + 
   scale_y_continuous("New", sec.axis = sec_axis(~./10, name = "Value"), 
       position = "left") +
   geom_line(data = DF[DF$Variable!="A",], aes(x = Column1, y = value, 
      fill = Variable))
   p1
```

The code works without error. However, I am unable to visualise the line graph created alongside the bar plot in the same chart. I have tried adjusting the scale but am unable to make it work.
Can I request some guidance.

Comment: Why so many `library` and `require` calls? You only use `ggplot` in the code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, just have to change the fill argument to group.

```
ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = Column1, y = value, colour = 
                        Variable)) +
  geom_bar(data = DF[DF$Variable == "A",], aes(x = Column1, y = value,
                                               fill=Variable), stat = 'identity') + 
  scale_y_continuous("New", sec.axis = sec_axis(~./10, name = "Value"), 
                     position = "left") +
  geom_line(data = DF[DF$Variable!="A",], aes(x = Column1, y = value, group = Variable))
```

Although I can't say it's very pretty to look at...

([image: messy plot])

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following might do what you want.

First of all, I will remake the dataset, this time setting the RNG seed.

```
set.seed(4821)    # Make the code reproducible

Column1 <- paste0('Month_', 1:30)
Variable <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", 'E')
DF <- data.frame(Column1, Variable)
nA <- sum(DF$Variable == "A")
DF$value <- 0
DF$value[DF$Variable == "A"] <- runif(nA, min = 10000, max = 50000)
DF$value[DF$Variable == "B"] <- runif(nA, min = 100, max = 500)
DF$value[DF$Variable == "C"] <- runif(nA, min = 100, max = 500)
DF$value[DF$Variable == "D"] <- runif(nA, min = 100, max = 500)
DF$value[DF$Variable == "E"] <- runif(nA, min = 100, max = 500)
```

Now the graph. Note that I have changed the scale of the secondary y axis from `10` to `100`.

```
library(ggplot2)

DFA <- subset(DF, Variable == "A")
DFX <- subset(DF, Variable != "A")

scale_y <- 100

p1 <- ggplot(DF) +
  geom_bar(data = DFA, aes(x = as.integer(sub("Month_", "", Column1)), y = value, fill = Variable), stat = 'identity') +
  geom_line(data = DFX, aes(x = as.integer(sub("Month_", "", Column1)), y = scale_y*value, colour = Variable)) +
  scale_y_continuous("New", sec.axis = sec_axis(~./scale_y, name = "Value"), position = "left") +
  scale_x_discrete("Column1", labels = as.integer(sub("Month_", "", Column1)))
p1
```

[image]